# "makes pointer from integer without a cast" when calling netif_napi_add

Tags: linux, c

The syntax for `netif_napi_add` is:

```
netif_napi_add(struct net_device *dev, struct napi_struct *napi,int (*poll)(struct napi_struct *, int), int weight)
```

It is used for initializing the napi structure. The problem is, when I use the function as:

```
netif_napi_add(wdev,rnapi,rrpoll(rnapi,20),16);
```

It's giving me a compilation warning:

```
warning: passing argument 3 of ‘netif_napi_add’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
/usr/src/linux-2.6.34.10-0.6/include/linux/netdevice.h:1089:6: note: expected ‘int (*)(struct napi_struct *, int)’ but argument is of type ‘int’
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The third argument to `netif_napi_add`, `int (*poll)(struct napi_struct *, int)`, is a [function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work) named `poll` that points to a function that takes a `struct napi_struct *` and an `int` and returns an `int`. You're calling `rrpoll` directly and passing its return value (an `int`) to `netif_napi_add`, instead of a function pointer. You probably want to just pass `rrpoll` to the function directly:

```
netif_napi_add(wdev, rnapi, &rrpoll, 16);
```

Comment: Note that the `&` is optional, since the name of a function usually "decays" to a pointer to the function: `netif_napi_add(wdev, rnapi, rrpoll, 16);`

Comment: @KeithThompson It's the "usually" that bothers me; it's never wrong, so I just include it always

Comment: The only exceptions are when the function name is the operand of `sizeof` or `_Alignof` (new in C11) (both of which are illegal), and when it's the operand of unary `&`.  It's safe to omit the `&`.  (But as you say, it's also save to include it.)

Answer (score 2):

The third argument should be a pointer to the function, not the return value, you should call it like that:

```
netif_napi_add(wdev,rnapi,&rrpoll,16);
```

(unless rrpoll returns a pointer to the function of the given type, but I don't think this is the case `:)` )